# Detect system standby/sleep/hibernate from .NET Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, power-state

In a Windows Service, I need to detect when the computer goes into sleep and when it wakes up, and run some code on these events. This needs to be done for sleep, standby and hibernate power modes.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Override the ServiceBase.OnPowerEvent() method.

Comment: Don't forget to set the ServiceBase.CanHandlePowerEvent = true; otherwise, you won't get any OnPowerEvents.

Comment: on my project the method OnPowerEvent is never triggered even though CanHandlePowerEvent  is set to true. Any idea on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure because I have never did it myself but recently I came accross OnSessionChange method. I can't promise it allows to catch sleep event, but may be studying it's documentation in MSDN or elswere can help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canhandlesessionchangeevent.aspx